# How to change controller response in filter to make the response structure consistent all over the API's using spring-boot

Tags: servlets, spring-boot, filter

I have implemented REST API using spring-boot application. All my API's are now returning response in JSON format for each entity. This response was consumed by other server which expects all these response are in same JSON format. For example;

All my responses should be accommodated within the following structure;

```
public class ResponseDto {
    private Object data;
    private int statusCode;
    private String error;
    private String message;
}
```

Currently spring-boot returns error responses in a different format. How to achieve this using filter.

Error message format;

```
{
   "timestamp" : 1426615606,
   "exception" : "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
   "status" : 400,
   "error" : "Bad Request",
   "path" : "/welcome",
   "message" : "Required String parameter 'name' is not present"
}
```

I need both error and successfull response are in same json structure all over my spring-boot application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved simply by utilizing a [ControllerAdvice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) and handling all possible exceptions, then returning a response of your own choosing.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    public ResponseDto handleThrowable(Throwable throwable) {
        // can get details from throwable parameter
        // build and return your own response for all error cases.
    }

    // also you can add other handle methods and return 
    // `ResponseDto` with different values in a similar fashion
    // for example you can have your own exceptions, and you'd like to have different status code for them

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ExceptionHandler(CustomNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseDto handleCustomNotFoundException(CustomNotFoundException exception) {
        // can build a "ResponseDto" with 404 status code for custom "not found exception"
    }
}
```

[Some great read on controller advice exception handlers](http://niels.nu/blog/2016/controller-advice-exception-handlers.html)

Comment: How should I get error message and error code inside this handlethrowable() method

Comment: @Achaius sorry I wrote my example wrong, you can get the message from the parameter to the `handleThrowable()` method, namely `throwable` in this example. But status code cannot be determined since by utilizing this structure, you are overriding any status code Spring predetermines depending on the exception type. But most of the time it will be 500, so you can just give status code 500 with the message for native exceptions, and for your own application exceptions you can have a separate handler with different status codes.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in servletFilter

Comment: @Achaius it is doable I think, https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/ but utilizing an advice is much more readable and easier don't you think?

Comment: I accept your point. But my worry is about status code. Any way thanks for your response. I will try this solution

Comment: I see, if you worry about native status codes coming from Spring that much, then this method is not OK, but I'd still recommend ignoring the status codes, you can have a different approach for example native exceptions can have their own error code, while your application exceptions can also have their own, since you are keeping the status codes in your response bean, you do not need to follow HTTP Status Codes. If that is not OK, I can delete my answer, since I do not agree to using a `servletFilter` at all.

Comment: to avoid the explicit `@ResponseBody` specifying at the each method the `@RestControllerAdvice` may be used instead